# Convert string to yyyyMMdd format

Tags: java

I have a `String` reading clients date of birth and I am trying to assign to another `String` but I need to assign in `yyyymmdd`  format. I am not sure what format client set his birth date.

Here is my code.

```
String birthDate = request.getClient().getBirthDate();
patient().setDob_yyyymmdd(birthdate);
```

Comment: You have to tell the client to you a specific format as you can't know what format they used except in some cases `20011223` could be 20th of Jan `1223` or some other combination.

Comment: Read [date time formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: Why are you getting the date of birth as a string to start with? Ideally, avoid string representations for as much of your code as you possibly can - a birth date should be a `LocalDate` other than at boundaries (persistence or API) where it may *need* to be converted into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to create a SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");//Put the incoming format
```

Then create a

```
Date date =sdf.parse(yourincomingdate);
```

Then create a DateFormat to transfor your Date to another format

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

String reportDate = df.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can guess in which format is the input date.
However, if you can manage to discover which is the input format, you can use the `SimpleDateFormat` class to convert `Date` objects to `Strings` and vice-versa.

```
String inputDate, inputFormat; //inputFormat may be, eg, "MM-dd-yyyy", that is the part you still need to find out
Date foo = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat).parse(inputDate);
String output = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(foo);
```